# Rewrite URL with htaccess - how to show fake url?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have code in htacces file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# this stops looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# this redirects the browser:
RewriteRule !^/?UL/india/ /UL/india/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?UL/india/ /UL/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when accessing `localhost/UL/`, It kept showing ' The page isn't redirecting properly '. What is the problem ?

I want show `localhost/UL/india/` in address bar for every request to the UL directory.
But the file that should be executed is `localhost/UL/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add an `L` flag to your rule and stop the looping:

```
# this stops looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# this redirects the browser:
RewriteRule !^/?UL/india/ /UL/india/ [L,R=301]
```

Then, after this, you want to match for `/UL/india/` and serve the index.php file:

```
RewriteRule ^/?UL/india/ /UL/index.php [L]
```

Comment: My requirement is when user enter localhost/UL/ it should redirect to localhost/UL/india/  but should execute the file localhost/UL/index.php....help me..provide full code..

Comment: @FrancisMV123 I provided the "full code" in my answer. Did you not even try it?

Comment: @FrancisMV123 It shows "`...`"? I put all those lines in a blank htaccess file (along with `RewriteEngine On`), and I hit any URL on the webserver and my browser's URL  address bar says `http://localhost/UL/india/` and I get served the contents of `/UL/index.php`.

Comment: @FrancisMV123 Edit your question and post your htaccess file, because these rules work perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @FrancisMV123 Those rules work fine for me. Are you sure you have the rewrite module loaded? If not, removing the `<IfModule>` lines would cause an error. Are you sure you have `AllowOverride All` set in your server/vhost config? Without that, your htaccess file will be completely ignored.